# Python 2.7 print() error

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, opensuse

I have a strange error using `sep`, `file`, (etc.) arguments of python's `print()` function.
I tried to google it out, dag around stackoverflow, and read [python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) but I came up with nothing.
I have attached a simple snippet, I would deeply appreciate any help.

```
# python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 19 2011, 20:41:43) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("blah"*10, sep=" | ")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("blah"*10, sep=" | ")
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

first

Comment: thanks you. it did solve the issue. so how come python documentation (see my update post) specifies otherwise? and, do you know where i can find the relevant documentation for native use of the `print()` function?

Comment: @MrRoth: Read the note on your link ;)

Answer (score 6):

In the 2.x series, `print` is a statement, while in 3.x it's a function. If you want in 2.6+ to have `print` as a function, you use `from __future__ import print_function` as the first import statement.

**Expect code to break though**

Answer (score 0):

The print function is specific to Python 3.
You have two solutions here:

Write

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

so you can use it as specified by cdarke.

Or you use print as a simple statement as it should be with older versions of Python (`print "Hello World"`).

Comment: The problem with using the old `print` statement is that the separator cannot be changed, unlike the current `print()` function.